# CSS - Fixed-Fluid Columns

Tags: html, css

In the body of my site, I am trying to create two columns - one on the far right with a fixed width (300px) for advertisements etc, and one on the left which will take up the remaining space on the page. How can this be accomplished in CSS?

Answer (score 7):

CSS :

```
.column-right {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.column-right .column-content {
    margin-left: 250px;
}

.column-left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -100%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="column-right">
    <div class="column-content">
        <strong>Right Column:</strong><em>Liquid</em>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column-left">
    <strong>Left Column:</strong><em>250px</em>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works, unlike the top answer. The fluid and fixed columns are the wrong way round, but apart from that all good.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tool to [generate fixed liquid columns](http://www.pagecolumn.com/liquidfixed/2_col_fix_liquid.htm) for placing adsense ads.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#right-column{
 width:300px;
 float:right;
}

#other-column{
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding-right:20px; /*to prevent text overlap as suggested in the comment*/
}
```

In HTML:

```
<div id='right-column'>
 <!-- ads here -->
</div>
<div id='other-column'>
 <!-- content here -->
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to have a padding-right on the #other-column declaration, so that the text in other-column does not wrap under the text in the right-column.

Comment: This does not work for me in firefox or IE.

[code]
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="ads">
</div>
[/code]

[code]
#content
{
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background: green;
}

#ads
{
 float: right;
 height: 500px;
 width: 200px;
 background: blue;
}
[/code]

Comment: try putting the ads div above the content div

Comment: You might also want to set a right margin of 300px on #other-column, so once the other-column gets longer than the ads, it does not fill up the space below but stays the same in width.

Comment: -1 because this answer does not appear to work in Chrome v22.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out the [YUI: CSS Grid Builder](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/builder/). It is a simple web interface where you specify what grid layout you are looking for, and they will provide you the html code you can use in combination with the [YUI Grids CSS framework](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/) to get your desired layout. One nice thing about the YUI Grids CSS framework is it has [good cross browser support](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/index.html#history) which saves you time getting it to work across different browsers. You can also reverse engineer the code that you are provided from the grid builder to get some ideas on how you can do it on your own. The settings you will want to use with the YUI: CSS Grid Builder to get your desired layout is as follows:

1. Body Size: 100%
2. Body Columns: Sidebar right 300px

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've found for this is to float the right column to the right and give the left column an absolute position with left:0 and right:300px.  This will make it fluid as if you gave it a width:80%, but it will be relative to the parent container in a different way.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tkane2000/dp9GZ/

One issue you might find with this is that since it's absolute, it won't naturally push down the elements below it.

Another possible solution would be to give the left column
width:100%
padding-right: 300px;

and the right (fixed width) column:
position: absolute:
top:0;
right:0;

You might need to set box-sizing:border-box on the left column.

This also as some limitations.  One that comes to mind, is that if you wanted the left column to have a border-right to separate each, the border would be on the wrong side of the right column.

Comment: and another thing is backward support for browsers that do no support with `left` and `right` put together.